# What is the purpose and result of using INADDR_ANY?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, multicast

In Python when we want to make a script that listens for multicast traffic we set the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` option of the socket with a value that consists of the multicast group address and the address of a local interface on which it will listen for the group's traffic.

Many examples on the Internet pass to `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` the `INADDR_ANY` wildcard address as the local interface, and *some* of them state that this will make the socket to listen on **all** interfaces for multicast packets. However the Linux ip(7) man page states that when using `INADDR_ANY`

> "an appropriate interface is chosen by the system"

and the freebsd man page says that it will choose the "default interface".

So either some answers online are wrong, or there's something that I'm missing here. I believe there's a confusion with `INADDR_ANY` when used as a parameter in `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`, and `INADDR_ANY` when used as a parameter in `bind()` (represented by an empty string) but I'm not really sure. Can someone please clarify what is happening with `INADDR_ANY` or `0.0.0.0` when used in `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` (i.e. it chooses the default interface or all interfaces) and if it behaves differently when used with `bind`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When `INADDR_ANY` is given as the address in a `bind` call, this causes the socket to listen on the given port for *any* network interface.

After calling `bind` in this way, you'll see an entry like this in the output of the `netstat` command:

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46162           0.0.0.0:*
```

This is a UDP socket that was bound to `INADDR_ANY` with port 46162.

When used as the interface address when setting the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` option, `INADDR_ANY` indicates that the OS will chose an interface to join the given multicast group on, i.e. the "default" network interface.

It does **not** mean that it will join the group on all interfaces.  To do that, you would need to itereate over all network interfaces and set the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` option on each one.

I've worked with Linux, Solaris, FreeBSD, and Windows, and none of them joins a multicast group on all interfaces when using `INADDR_ANY`.